# Convert date from one format to another - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I convert date from mm-dd-yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in AngularJS. Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/uoeuuHD8GOkPxj5LOlE5?p=preview

```
$scope.date = '07-28-2016';
```

{{ data | date:'filter'}} //should return 07/28/2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start with an actual `Date` instance

```
$scope.date = new Date('2016-07-28'); // ISO 8601 date formats are less ambiguous
```

then use the `date` filter, ie

```
{{ date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ay2DDwzxQTiBx34bEO5d?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer.